# Ant and termite detection using PIR

Tags: gpio, sensor

I would like to detect **ant and termite** using either one of the following sensor. [**PIR**](http://www.ebay.com/itm/New-HC-SR501-Infrared-PIR-Motion-Sensor-Module-for-Arduino-Raspberry-pi-/261455286898) or [**infrared object detection**](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Obstacle-Avoidance-Sensor-Module-Infrared-Module-Reflection-Photoelectric-Sensor-/321594140528?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item4ae0812770) sensor. Is it possible to detect insects with them or it can detect only larger sized animals ? I came to know that these things will detect these **spiders and ants** by this [**link**](http://www.candlepowerforums.com/vb/showthread.php?287257-Passive-Infra-Red-detector-triggering-too-often). Does this work?

Comment: Note that concerns bugs on the lens itself, not merely in the field of view.

Comment: You may find this challenging as Ants are cold blooded and do not generally radiate heat ( infrared ), maybe you could use a machine vision approach with a webcam?

Answer (score 1):

This might be tough unless you get line-of-sight.

Here's the [kind of result Google](http://www.bmva.org/bmvc/2010/conference/paper108/paper108.pdf) provides that might be useful.  [Getting into that](http://opencv.org/) is not for the faint of heart.

Perhaps a chemical sensor would be more beneficial in your case?  You might be able to detect chemical markers for specific insect types.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should use microwaves. Ants are really small, any thing you would use, it should be precisely setup - microwaves with some millimeter wave length could does the job. May be in a thin stripe where the wall stick with floor. Possible you could use commercial microwave motion detector, with some fine tunning or remodeling.